# Save an array or map in Firebase Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I have an array of maps and i should save the array in firebase database.
when i do  the update it remove the key and doesn't save

How can I save my array?

[image]

Comment: Please share the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it is quite useful when asking for help on code-related questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve .... this is my solution :

```
  remainingPhotos[position] = {  Key: originalPhotoArray[i], 
                                 Thumb: arrayPhotoThumb[i], 
                                 Title: titleArray[i], 
                                 Width: widthArray[i], 
                                 Height: heightArray[i]
                              };
```

For each element to add the element in json format and found!!